# sending link lists using NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, linked-list, nsdata

i am currently in the middle of implementing the network side of my multi player game. So far i am sending classes across by serialising my objects into NSData. The trouble lies in the fact that i have link lists within my class referencing other objects of the same type. If i transferred all the objects across and decoded on the receiving end using initWithCoder: (NSCoder *) decoder would the objects within the class still hold the correct references? If not can anyone recommend a clean solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSCoder should work fine for this.  When you encode, encode the head of the list and use the list structure itself to guide the rest.  Say the list has a string for it's data and a simple forward link.  Just encode the head...

```
// in ListNode.m

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)encoder {

    [encoder encodeObject:self.theString forKey:@"thisIsMyListsData"];
    if (self.nextNode) {
        [encoder encodeObject:self.nextNode forKey:@"nextNode"];
    }
}
```